# Changing URL in multisite

Tags: multisite

After changing the main site URL from IP address to a domain name (the "Site Address" field), it shows the following error when accessing "Network Admin" page:

> Error establishing a database connection

It is important to note that the site is accessible via its new URL, however "Network Admin" and all the multisite settings are not.

Comment: _how_ did you change it? Did you do an SQL query to change it? If so, is the IP address the same number of characters as your domain name? Or different? If it's different then you've corrupted a lot of PHP serialised data structures. Otherwise, migrating a sites URL is a bit more involved than just changing it in the settings

Comment: I assume additional changes needed to be made in the DB, but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: yes, you're trying to perform a standard site migration, any site migration article or tutorial applies here, narrowing your search to be specific to the root multisite blog is unnecessary and does not help your cause. Look up any standard well regarded article on how to migrate a sites URL, there are no special multisite steps

Comment: I don’t think I fully understand your answer. A site migration is required? where do  I move the site to?

Comment: a site URL migration, aka changing olddomain.com to newdomain.com, there is a process necessary to do this that you have not done, it's not enough to change the site url, you have to change _all_ URLs across the entire database using a tool that can deserialise, update, then re-serialise the PHP values that will be broken by a naive update query

Comment: Tom, thank you very much! What finally has solved my problem is setting the new domain name inside wp-config.php parameters  - "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE", "WP_HOME", "WP_SITEURL".

Answer (score 0):

Probably this due to the siteurl setting in db. But for multisite, how did you configure for mult

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='YOUR_SITE_URL' WHERE option_name='siteurl'
```

Comment: Something is wrong, mariadb prompts "->" after running this command.

Comment: got it to run but 0 rows affected.

Comment: SQL update string replace queries will corrupt and break any serialised PHP values if the length changes, it's not enough to change the `siteurl`. Also this query will only work for single sites, and doesn't account for multisites